# Do Unique validation on multiple fields in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I want to do "unique" validation on multiple fields. I have written below validation rule but not sure how to include brand_id and company_id in it

```
$request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|unique:products',
            'company_id' => 'required',
            'brand_id' => 'required',
 ]);
```

So what I am trying to do is, ADD PRODUCT but check if the name is unique for the given company_id and brand_id. How can I do that?

Comment: So the `company_id` and `brand_id` is coming with the request?

Comment: yes, is coming with request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Rule::unique()` function to add custom conditions to unique validation.

```php
$request->validate([
    'company_id' => 'required',
    'brand_id' => 'required',
    'name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        Rule::unique('products')->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('company_id', request('company_id'));
            $query->where('brand_id', request('brand_id'));
        }),
    ],
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the bail rule to the attribute:

```
$request->validate([
    'name'          => 'bail|required|string|unique:products',
    'company_id'    => 'bail|required',
    'brand_id'      => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **additional** `wheres` after the *ignore* options (the `NULL,id` below), e.g.:

```php
$request->validate([
    'company_id' => 'required',
    'brand_id' => 'required',
    'name' => 'required|string|unique:products,name,NULL,id,company_id,'.request('company_id').',brand_id,'.request('brand_id'),           '
 ]);
```